# Scala (2.11.1) & play framework (2.x) if statement with variable in Flash scope

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Heads up: I'm a total newbie to `Play! framework` & `Scala`

In my controller, I set a variable (of type String) in the **flash scope**

```
 flash("success", "Well done!");
```

In the Scala template, let's call it `pageName.scala.html` , I can display its value such as:

```
 @flash.get("success")
```

But I want to add some html around it: only show the relevant HTML & flash variable value when necessary. Here is some pseudo-code describing what I'd like to do:

```
 if successVarInFlashScope is not empty
   <div class="global-notification__inner">
     <div class="global-notification__msg">@flash.get("success")</div>
   </div>
 end if
```

I tried a few different things but no luck.

I also looked into the `Play framework documentation` & on `StackOverflow` but no luck either.

**Resources:**

- [www.scala-lang.org](http://www.scala-lang.org)
- [www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaSessionFlash](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaSessionFlash)
- [www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Scala:**

The `get` method on `Flash` returns an `Option[String]` that you can `map`:

```
@flash.get("success").map { msg =>
   <div class="global-notification__inner">
     <div class="global-notification__msg">@msg</div>
   </div>
}
```

**Java:**

`Http.Flash` in Play Java extends `java.util.HashMap`, so `get` will either return `String` or `null`. Unfortunately, we can't be as elegant as the above code in Java, so an `if` will have to do.

```
if(@flash.get("success") != null) {
   <div class="global-notification__inner">
     <div class="global-notification__msg">@flash.get("success")</div>
   </div>
}
```

Or `if(@flash.containsKey("success"))`

Comment: great, answer now accepted. I also did some clean-up: removed my comments (as deprecated) & remove my answer.